# Android studio Gradle upgrading issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I imported an older project built in Android studio, which was using Gradle 0.14.0. I am now using Android Studio v 1.1.0. I was prompted to update the Gradle plugin from 0.14.0 to 1.1.0 which I did. I also made the necessary changes. Now, I am getting the below error:

```
Error:(1, 0) No such property: GRADLE_SUPPORTED_VERSIONS for class: com.saikoa.dexguard.h
```

My build.gradle is:

```
    apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appu.barat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        release {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
}

buildscript
{
    dependencies
            {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
//                classpath ':dexguard:'
            }
}
```

Do you know what I could do to resolve the above error?

Comment: I've struggled with problems like this as well, and found it was easier to just make a brand new project, create activities with the same names as your old project, and then copy/paste all the xml/java.

Comment: Creating a new project is not an option; I've to make changes to the same one because the code is already there in an online repository. Any help or guidance?

Comment: Are you using DexGuard plugin 6.1.+. ?

Comment: How can I check for the current DexGuard version? Where can I download 6.1.+ from if I don't have it already?